# Icons are not smooth

Tags: icons, 15.04

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 15.04. But all icons on my left panel are choppy. Is this a bug of new ubuntu or there is a way I can correct it ?
I am attaching the screen shot of the icons.

[image]

Comment: An image of these icons might help (upload it to a images hosting and edit into the question the url to the image; someone with enough rep will edit the image into the question)

Comment: Please check the image I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with some resolution and iconsize values.
Go to `Settings -> Appearance -> Look` its the slider at the bottom.
Try chaning the size of the icons one step up or down.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the problem is still there. Nothing changed by changing icon size.

Comment: Please add the picture to your question then, as Rinzwind suggested.

Comment: Please check the image I have attached.

Comment: Strange, it looked the same on my screen. Have you tried different settings for the size? Only every other one worked for me.